# How do I get a webcam working with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, webcam

Previously I've put working webcam code into my application, but now it's not working when I updated to AngularJS v1.5.0. I am using [webcam-directive](https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive) which was working perfectly with v1.3.0.

Here is my code:

```
<webcam placeholder="selfiePlaceHolder"
  on-stream="onStream(stream)"
  on-access-denied="onError(err)" on-streaming="onSuccess(video)">
</webcam>
```

But now it's giving following error with AngularJS v1.5.0:

```
Uncaught Error: [$parse:isecdom] Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression: onSuccess(video)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$parse/isecdom?p0=onSuccess(video)
```

I also tried to use a different solution with [AngularJS ng-Camera](https://github.com/bcabanes/ng-camera) but even its demo page is not working for me.

**Note:** I know the issue is that we can't access the DOM from the newer version of AngularJS, but the same code works with the older version. I need to know how to pass the "Video" DOM object to the controller.

Comment: What is `video` in the expression `onSuccess(video)`? It's obviously a DOM element, but I'm just making sure. The solution is not to include the DOM element in that expression. But to really solve your problem, you're going to need to provide more context so we understand how/why the DOM element is being used in the expression and come up w/a work around.

Comment: PS: I just took a look at the webcam-directive on Github. It sounds like you might be able to use this [channel thing](https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive#set-a-channel-to-bind-data) to get access to the `video` element.

Comment: Yes "video" is DOM object. Actually "video" Will reference the video element on success. channel thing also not working :(

Comment: In my answer, I provided an example for how to use the `channel` attribute to get access to the video DOM element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the solution to the problem. Two things need to be done:

First In HTML:

```html
<webcam channel="channel" 
        on-streaming="onSuccess()" 
        on-error="onError(err)" 
        on-stream="onStream(stream)"></webcam>
```

Secondly, in the controller, you can access the DOM video with the following code:

```
 $scope.onSuccess = function () {
        // The video element contains the captured camera data
        _video = $scope.channel.video;
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.patOpts.w = _video.width;
            $scope.patOpts.h = _video.height;
            //$scope.showDemos = true;
        });
    };
```

Here is a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/qww6g0a6/).

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in my answer, and did in my plunkr example that i had linked at the bottom of my answer: https://plnkr.co/edit/jbPZiS6trhknVig1B4bW. Good that you got it working.

Comment: The [Working Example..](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/qww6g0a6/) in the answer is really helpful! Thanks for sharing your code.

Comment: @Imran Is there a way to open the web cam on button click instead of loading it on page load?

Comment: @TonyRoczz I think u can do in AngualrJS using ng-show or Hide, on button click.

Answer (score 3):

It is a potential error generally occurs when an expression tries to access a DOM node since it is restricted accessing to DOM nodes via expressions by AngularJS because it might cause to execute arbitrary Javascript code.

The `$parse:isecdom error` is related to an invoke to a function by event handler when an event handler which returns a DOM node, like below:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction()">Click</button>
$scope.myFunction = function() {
  return DOM;
}
```

To fix this issue, avoid access to DOM nodes and avoid returning DOM nodes from event handlers. (Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecdom)

Adding an explicit return might solve this issue as detailed here: [CoffeeScript - Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838497/coffeescript-referencing-dom-nodes-in-angular-expressions-is-disallowed)

Comment: yes I know the issue, We need solution to above problem so that webcam works with AngularJS. Like how to pass "Video" DOM object to controller...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get webcam-directive working using the channel suggestion from the comment above, based on the example on the [github page](https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive).

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.myChannel = {
        // the fields below are all optional
        videoHeight: 800,
        videoWidth: 600,
        video: null // Will reference the video element on success
    };
}
```

In the `onSuccess`(`on-streaming` attr) and `onStream`(`on-stream` attr) callback the `video` property  of `myChannel` was filled in with the video DOM element (and then it would obviously be available to everything else in the controller too). According to the comment in the example code though, you should wait to access it at least until `onSuccess`. [Here is a working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jbPZiS6trhknVig1B4bW)

Comment: Yes its gud to move, but still error exists:

As videoElem is undefined still.. 
$scope.onSuccess = function(videoElem) {
  // The video element contains the captured camera data
  _video = videoElem;
  alert('videoElem '+videoElem);
  $scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.patOpts.w = _video.width;
   $scope.patOpts.h = _video.height;
   $scope.showDemos = true;
  });
 };