# unable to the access the local webcam after the code is deployed in server

Tags: java, image, camera, webcam

I am using webcam to capture the images from my program. When i run the locally on my machine webcam of my local laptop is getting opened . But when i deploy the code in server ....Webcam is not opening .

Is it trying to open the webcam of server system?

I am using the following code open the camera

```
webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);
Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();

webcam.setViewSize(size);

panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
panel.setPreferredSize(size);
panel.setFPSDisplayed(true);
panel.start();
```

---

Comment: Your question is unclear in giving the impression that you basically ask "If I run a program on two different machines, why isn't the webcan always opened on the first machine?". Please explain more to prevent that misunderstanding. If that actually is the question you are asking, then please explain how you imagine that the server should know to open the webcam on a different machine, which one and how.

Comment: when i developed the code in the my local machine it was working fine...after i deployed the code in the server and try to access the application through url .webcam failed to open..my application have the functionality to capture the image through Webcam ..webcam failed to open through the url with code deployed in server

Comment: What do you mean by "through the url"? Which kind of URL? I am not asking for the actual URL, just whether it is a URL of your local machine and whether that local machine is actually a server which is accessable via the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code invoke by Servlet or related API which is server-side implementation, and that will work for specific server only. But if you have to access client Cams and send it over your system then you have to implement same functionality with JS or Type script, exp: Angular, Any Js based frame work.

Below I m sharing discussion for how to do it in Angular:
[How do I get a webcam working with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237992/how-do-i-get-a-webcam-working-with-angularjs)

Hope this will help!!